# How to compare value with most recent column entry above when conditional formatting?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to highlight decreases within a column, highlighting the cell if it contains a lesser value than the cell above it. However, I'm running into an issue where an above empty cell = 0, so a cell might not be highlighted when there's a missing value in between a decrease. Ideally, I'd like a way to tell google sheets to look for the most recent entry in the cells above and to skip over comparing the value with an empty cell.

As an example, my rules are:

- if cell is empty, no highlight
- if custom formula is `=B3<B2` , highlight yellow

I'll need to change the B2 part I imagine, but I'm just not sure what to put in its place

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mobhI.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

*Apple to range*: `B3:B`

*Custom formula*: `=(B3<lookup(9^9,B$2:B2))*len(B3)`

[image]